# Sublime Text 3 Incremental Selection

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I want to know is there an analog command in Sublime to Pycharms Cmd(Ctrl)+W?

This is what she does in Pycharm:

- Press Ctrl+W to select the word where the caret is currently located.
- Press Ctrl+W successively to extend selection to the next containing node (for example, an expression, a paired tag, an entire conditional block, a method body, a class, a group of vararg arguments, etc.)

While extending selection, keep in mind the following:

- Pressing Ctrl+W successively in plain text or comments extends the selection first to the current sentence, then to the current paragraph.
- Pressing Ctrl+W successively inside a list, dictionary, or a list of arguments or parameters, selects an element of the list, then the right or left comma and a neighbouring space (if any), then the contents of the list without parentheses, and finally the enclosing parentheses.
- Press Ctrl+Shift+W to shrink selection in the reverse order (from the outermost container to the word where the caret currently resides).
  Tip

The selection extends or shrinks according to capitalization, if the Use "CamelHumps" words is enabled on the Editor. Smart Keys settings page.

If you want to make selection according to capitalization, using double-click, make sure that the option Honor CamelHumps words... is selected on the Editor settings page.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming question and answers. Perhaps you should ask text editor questions on [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 9):

Without using a plugin:

- **Expand selection to scope (`Ctrl + Shift + Space` / `CMD + Shift + Space`)**
- Expand selection to brackets (`Ctrl + Shift + M` / `Ctrl + Shift + M`)
- Expand selection to indentation (`Ctrl + Shift + J` / `CMD + Shift + J`)

Answer (score 1):

There is [ExpandRegion](https://github.com/aronwoost/sublime-expand-region) plugin, which you can install using [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation). I just tried it and it's pretty good. However I did not find an option to shrink the selection (only expand), but I may have overlooked it.

If you use it, you will also need to define your own keybinding for the command. Description on how to do that is in README.md file on the plugin's GitHub page.

Comment: add a shortcut in user keybindings `"keys": ["super+u"],
   "command": "expand_region",
   "args": {"undo": true},
   "context": [{ "key": "expand_region_soft_undo" }]` to enalbe shrinks selection with `super+u`.

Comment: { "keys": ["option+up"], "command": "expand_selection", "args": {"to": "smart"} },
{ "keys": ["option+down"], "command": "soft_undo" },

expand and shrink by option+up/down like Jetbrains idea